# How do I add an HTML News Ticker(Scrolling Text) in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: newsfeed

I am currently using SharePoint 2010 and I have a landing page which needs to display a News Ticker(Scrolling Text News Feed).

Which part of the HTML code do I insert in the field provided when I go:

Edit Web Part > Source Editior > HTML Edititor Window

What do I need to have the News Ticker read from a URL my company will provide?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to consume an RSS feed?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this with a custom web part, or there are 3rd party web parts with this functionality already. One is from Amrein engineering. I've used a couple of their parts before, and they work fine. The Amrein parts don't have as many options as the parts from other vendors, but that also means you can have it up and running in a couple minutes (no, I don't work for them, sorry for the sales pitch).

http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5752

Comment: heh. Just noticed the date of this post. Well, if you're still looking for a solution 2 years later, the above will work... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be abel to implemente a Newschannel like newsticker. This will be done with a huhge of javascript or a custom webpart i think.

Otherwise ist to add a rss feed panel, which displays the news into it. 
(When the site supports Rss)

Answer (score -1):

Found this article quite useful for scrolling text, check out

http://sharepointlogics.com/2014/07/sharepoint-scrolling-announcement-news.html

Comment: Can you provide some context for your link? Link only answers are generally frowned upon: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer